# Configure Rockset as a DataSource for Grafana

Tags: grafana, rockset

We have rockset collection, in frankfurt region, I need to configure an Grafana server where we can easily monitor the data of collection.
We configured an grafana server, and added Rockset as data source by following [Rockset as Data Source](https://github.com/rockset/rockset-grafana-backend#installation) documentation.

I am using following Query:

> `SELECT TIME_BUCKET(MINUTES(5), requestLogs_v1._event_time) AS _event_time, requestLogs_v1.Id, requestLogs_v1.status, requestLogs_v1.duration, requestLogs_v1.name, requestLogs_v1.service, TYPEOF(companyName) FROM workspace.requestLogs_v1 WHERE time is not null and Id > 1 ORDER BY time desc LIMIT 250`

- When I add the query in garafna it only returns, column which has Integer type.
- The string or other values are not retuned, and when I try to fetch column which are string then it return "no usable column found" error.
- When I try to run the same query in Rockset it returns the result normally.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone

- I raise same query to Rockset Support, and got reply from them.
- As of now(20/12/23) The rockset plugin for Grafana only supports
  numeric fields for Visualization.
- Rockset team has updated the documentation as,
  https://docs.rockset.com/documentation/docs/grafana Now it include
  the latest informations.

[image: Rockset Mail Reply]